# Error with sqlite and python-Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

From what I've read this is a common error-I'm reading a tab delimited text file into an sqlite database, and while there are 15 columns, in some rows, there are no data. For example, here is a chunk of my text file I'm reading in:

http://www.vta.org/schedules/tdl/SC_902NO_WK.tdl

I'm just reading in the actual times. The problem is, for example, not every column is completely filled with times, which is why I'm getting

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses >15, and there are 8 supplied.

How do I deal with the empty values in the text file?

Here is my code

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
import csv
con = lite.connect('vta.db')

with con:

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NB_902_Wkdy')
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE NB_902_Wkdy ( Train_Num INT primary key, Winchester TEXT,            Bascom TEXT, Fruitdale TEXT, Diridon TEXT,
```

Convention TEXT, Santa_Clara TEXT, Civic_Center TEXT, Metro TEXT, Tasman TEXT, Old_Ironsides TEXT, Fair_Oaks TEXT, Lockheed TEXT, Whisman TEXT, Mountain_View TEXT) """)

```
creader = csv.reader(open('NB_902_Wkdy', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')#, quotechar='|')
for t in creader:
     cur.execute('INSERT INTO NB_902_Wkdy VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', t)

creader.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what "deal with" means, but assuming that you want to insert `NULL` values into the missing fields, you just have to append them to `t` until you have enough values:

```
for t in creader:
    while len(t) < 15:
        t += (None,)
    cur.execute(..., t)
```